# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cloneNodes: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: python, cython

I'm facing this issue when I run this command and it creates a makecpython.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("cloneNodes", ["app/v3/impl/cloneNodes.pyx"])]

setup(
    name = 'arr',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules,
    compiler_directives={'language_level' : "3"}
)
```

Later I run my file to clone the nodes to this is created, this is the clonenode.py file made:

```
from cpython cimport *

def cloningNodes(matrix,toClone):
    cdef Py_ssize_t matrixSize=PyList_Size(matrix),cloneSize=PyList_Size(toClone),newSize=matrixSize+cloneSize,i,j
    output=PyList_New(newSize)
    for i in range(matrixSize):
        currentMatrixRow=<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(matrix,i)
        Py_INCREF(currentMatrixRow)
        PyList_SET_ITEM(output,i,
            currentMatrixRow)
        for j in range(cloneSize):
            currentRow=<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(output,i)
            PyList_Append(currentRow,<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(
                    <object>PyList_GET_ITEM(matrix,i),PyLong_AsSsize_t(<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(toClone,j))
                )
            )
    for i in range(cloneSize):
        toCloneRow=<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(output,PyLong_AsSsize_t(<object>PyList_GET_ITEM(toClone,i)))
        Py_INCREF(toCloneRow)
        PyList_SET_ITEM(output,i+matrixSize,toCloneRow)
    return output
```

Now I have to run the uvicorn main app thus instead of showing the link it goes to the dll error:

```
  uvicorn main:app
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\nkgad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\uvicorn.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 425, in main
    run(app, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 447, in run
    server.run()
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 68, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 76, in serve
    config.load()
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 448, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 24, in import_from_string
    raise exc from None
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
  File "c:\users\nkgad\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app.api import app
  File ".\app\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .v3.controller.route_info_controller import RouteController
  File ".\app\v3\controller\route_info_controller.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..impl.vrp_impl import VRPImpl
  File ".\app\v3\impl\vrp_impl.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .open_route_map_impl import OpenRouteImpl
  File ".\app\v3\impl\open_route_map_impl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cloneNodes import cloningNodes
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cloneNodes: The parameter is incorrect.
```

How can I resolve this DLL load failure issue?